# QGIS Group Points Together Based on Multiple Attributes

Tags: qgis, distance, grouping

I'm using QGIS and I want to group points that are:

- within 20m of each other (as I have multiple mobile basestations on the same site)
- based on a categorical variable (the mobile operator)

I have 139,742 points that I expect to reduce to around 30,000 by the time I've grouped those within 20m. This 30,000 then should divide between the major mobile operators.

I want to do this without losing all of the data linked with those points. A good way may be to select points based on these conditions and then add in a new column with a shared number to indicate the grouping. Any ideas on how I may do this?

Answer (score 3):

You probably want to create clusters.
You may start with [Scipy Point Clustering plugin](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/ScipyPointClustering/).
Have a look first to this nice [tutorial](http://www.ekazakov.info/projects/abc_tutorial.html).